# magento web service filter product list error Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I'm using visual studio 2010 service reference to consume magento soap v2 api web service.

php 5.3.8, magento 1.6 install on windows 7 iis 7.5

I can log in and list all the product, but as soon as i put a filter there is an exception

Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

php error log:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Magento1620\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

```
static void TestMagentoSoapV2Wcf()
    {
        MagentoService magentoService = new MagentoService();

        MageSvcRef.associativeEntity assoEntity = new MageSvcRef.associativeEntity();
        assoEntity.key = "like";
        assoEntity.value = "n2610";

        MageSvcRef.complexFilter complexFilter = new MageSvcRef.complexFilter();
        complexFilter.key = "sku";
        complexFilter.value = assoEntity;

        MageSvcRef.complexFilter[] compFilters = new MageSvcRef.complexFilter[1];
        compFilters[0] = complexFilter;

        MageSvcRef.filters filters = new MageSvcRef.filters();
        filters.complex_filter = compFilters;

        string sessionId = magentoService.login("zzc000", "zzc000");

        var products = magentoService.catalogProductList(sessionId, filters, string.Empty);
    }
```

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Magento bug, but I'm not sure since I'm not a PHP developer, it may only reflect Magento and PHP install on windows

modify this file

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api\V2.php
```

line 57-62

```
foreach ($filters->complex_filter as $_filter) {                
            $_value = $_filter->value;
            $preparedFilters[$_filter->key] = array(
                $_value->key => $_value->value
            );
        }
```

to

```
foreach ($filters->complex_filter as $_field => $_filter) {
            $preparedFilters[$_field] = array(
                    $_filter->key => $_filter->value
            );
        }
```

I also notice that in different V2.php file, this piece of code is written differently. The customer API is the same as product, but the order API is written like this

```
foreach ($filters->complex_filter as $_filter) {
            $_value = $_filter->value;
            if(is_object($_value)) {
                $preparedFilters[][$_filter->key] = array(
                    $_value->key => $_value->value
                );
            } elseif(is_array($_value)) {
                $preparedFilters[][$_filter->key] = array(
                    $_value['key'] => $_value['value']
                );
            } else {
                $preparedFilters[][$_filter->key] = $_value;
            }
        }
```

anyone can point out the correct array usage in PHP?

Comment: The API documentation can be flat out wrong at times.

Go to, yourmagentoinstall.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl to get a list of all the api calls and their expected arguments.

filters = ['filter' => [['key' => 'value']], 'complex_filter' => [['updated_at' => ['gt' => '2013-12-31 20:18:59']]]