# Magento WS-I compliant v2 API WSDL web service SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sessionId' property

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento v2 web service in WS-I compliant mode

when try to list product i get exception

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'sessionId' property
```

my code is listed below

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/Magento1620/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));

    $sessionId = $proxy->login(array(
        'username' => "zzc000",
        'apiKey' => "zzc000"
    ));

    $filters = array(
        'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
    );

    $products = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filters);
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Hi. Is there any other working function from the magento soap api in your project, or Is this your first  shoot on the first api?

Comment: @AndreasRohde 
this is a fresh magento install with sample data on windows 7, iis 7.5, php 5.3.8 
This is the first time to consume it within php client, only the login works. I can call it from C# .NET.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In **WS-I mode**, there are some **minor differences** in using the API.

1. The result of $proxy->login() is an object. You need to extract the sessionId.
2. When calling $proxy->catalogProductList(), you need to provide the parameters in an associative array (just like you did with $proxy->login()).

Please try this:

```
<?php

try {
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/Magento1620/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));

    $session = $proxy->login(array(
        'username' => "zzc000",
        'apiKey' => "zzc000"
    ));
    $sessionId = $session->result;

    $filters = array(
       'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
    );

    $products = $proxy->catalogProductList(array("sessionId" => $sessionId, "filters" => $filters));

    echo '<h1>Result</h1>';
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($products);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<h1>Error</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
}
```

The same applies to other method calls for the WS-I compliant v2 SOAP API.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8868668/1015655) @MatthiasZeis  
Thank you, it works!!! but i have to pass the filter in a weird way to get it work, am i going the wrong route?  
`$filters = array(
   'complex_filter' => array(
     array(
       'key' => 'product_id',
       'value' => array(
         'key' => 'eq',
         'value' => '18'
         )
       )
     )
   );
 
 $products = $proxy->catalogProductList(array("sessionId" => $sessionId, "filters" => $filters));`

Comment: If you need information for a single product, use:
    $products = $proxy->catalogProductInfo(array("sessionId" => $sessionId, "productId" => 18));
For filtering the product list, you may need to use complex filter and yes, this can be quite weird. ;-)

Comment: can you help me to look at the problem I had in another post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8867327/1015655)

Comment: I had a look at it and could reproduce the error with PHP 5.3 on a Linux system. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the complex filter to work with PHP. The code seems kinds of flawed to me. You could file a bug report with Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking) and hope to get a response from the core team.

Comment: How do plugin authors support WS-I mode being on or off with the V2 API? If our soap call parameters need to be an assoc array if ON and passed individually if OFF, it makes it very difficult... help?

Comment: @MatthiasZeis Now my values return as Objects, how can i return as XML my code : https://justpaste.it/3rwzs